# Open WAZE with Titanium App

Tags: android, appcelerator, waze

i am developing an app where the user needs to go to some place, so, my client wants to use the WAZE App but i cant make it work in Android.

Acording to WAZE i must do this:

```
try
{
    String url = "waze://?q=Hawaii";
    Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( url ) );
    startActivity( intent );
}
catch ( ActivityNotFoundException ex  )
{
  Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( "market://details?id=com.waze" ) );
 startActivity(intent);
}
```

So, i am converting that to Titanium Code like this:

```
            try{
               var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
                   action: Ti.Android.ACTION_VIEW,
                   data: waze
               });                           
               Titanium.Android.startService(intent);                     
             }               
             catch(e){
               Titanium.Platform.openURL("market://details?id=com.waze");
             }
```

("waze" is a string var where i have the url)

But always goes to the "Catch" ad takes me to the Store.
( Waze is already installed on my device )

this is the link where you can find the information in waze homepage.
https://www.waze.com/es-419/about/dev

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create a new activity, not start a service. I believe your code in the try block should be:

```
try{
           var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
               action: Ti.Android.ACTION_VIEW,
               data: waze
           });                           
           Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);                   
         }               
         catch(e){
           Titanium.Platform.openURL("market://details?id=com.waze");
         }
```